# apache2.conf RewriteEngine not working withc specific statements

Tags: apache, .htaccess

I have a website which uses phprouter so I edited my apache2.conf and the .htaccess files. It used to worked yesterday but now it's now. I haven't changed anything just reinstalled my computer. The error appears when the following code is active in the `apache2.conf` file.

When I try to restert the apache server the following text appears:

> Job for apache2.service failed because the control process exited with error code.
>
> See "systemctl status apache2.service" and "journalctl -xeu apache2.service" for details.

```
<Directory "/var/www/html">
    RewriteEngine On
    #website location
    RewriteBase /
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.+)$ index.php?uri=$1 [QSA,L]
</Directory>
```

*Again:* It worked with the code above but after a reinstall it doesn't.
Any idea why?

apache2.conf:

```
DefaultRuntimeDir ${APACHE_RUN_DIR}
PidFile ${APACHE_PID_FILE}
Timeout 300
KeepAlive On
MaxKeepAliveRequests 100
KeepAliveTimeout 5
User ${APACHE_RUN_USER}
Group ${APACHE_RUN_GROUP}
HostnameLookups Off
ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
LogLevel warn
IncludeOptional mods-enabled/*.load
IncludeOptional mods-enabled/*.conf
Include ports.conf
<Directory />
    Options FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride None
    Require all denied
</Directory>
<Directory /usr/share>
    AllowOverride None
    Require all granted
</Directory>
<Directory /var/www/>
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride None
    Require all granted
</Directory>
#<Directory /srv/>
#   Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
#   AllowOverride None
#   Require all granted
#</Directory>
AccessFileName .htaccess
<FilesMatch "^\.ht">
    Require all denied
</FilesMatch>
    LogFormat "%v:%p %h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %O \"%{Referer}i\" \"%{User-Agent}i\""     vhost_combined
LogFormat "%h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %O \"%{Referer}i\" \"%{User-Agent}i\"" combined
LogFormat "%h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %O" common
LogFormat "%{Referer}i -> %U" referer
LogFormat "%{User-agent}i" agent
IncludeOptional conf-enabled/*.conf
IncludeOptional sites-enabled/*.conf
Include /etc/phpmyadmin/apache.conf

<Directory "/var/www">
    FileETag All
    Options +FollowSymLinks +MultiViews
    AddType application/x-httpd-php .php
    AllowOverride None
    Require all granted       
</Directory>

<Directory "/var/www/html">
    RewriteEngine On
    #website location
    RewriteBase /
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.+)$ index.php?uri=$1 [QSA,L]
</Directory>

# Disable directory browsing
Options All -Indexes

# Hide the contents of directories
IndexIgnore *

# Deny crucial files
<Files .htaccess>
    AllowOverride All
    Order allow,deny
    Deny from all
</Files>
<Files header.php>
    Order allow,deny
    Deny from all
</Files>
<Files footer.php>
    Order allow,deny
    Deny from all
</Files>

# Custom error document
ErrorDocument 403 /403.php
ErrorDocument 404 /404.php
```

.htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On
#website location
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ index.php?uri=$1 [QSA,L]
```

Comment: @IMSoP I have changed my ubuntu 22.04 to ubuntu 22.10

Comment: Well, that's quite a long way from "not changing anything", isn't it? Did you look at "systemctl status apache2.service" and "journalctl -xeu apache2.service" as the error message suggests?

Comment: @IMSoP I have saved all the files on my pendrive and just dragged the files to my new system so basically not changed anything

Comment: Sure, but you've changed lots of things *about the system*. For instance, you may now be running a different version of Apache, or of PHP; or some default system settings may have changed.

Comment: The Apache config you've posted is incomplete so this is hard to debug. Is mod_rewrite enabled? (What is your doc-root? Where is this defined?) If your doc-root is `/var/www/html` then the `<Directory>` block in the server config is superfluous if you have `.htaccess` as well (and where is this `.htaccess` file?). But what enables the `.htaccess` overrides? The one instance of `AllowOverride All` in the code you posted is invalid in this context. You are also mixing Apache 2.4 and Apache 2.2 auth directives which could be another source of error.